# Input of apache_beam.examples.wordcount

Tags: python, apache-flink, apache-beam

I was trying to run the beam Python-SDK example, but I had problem in reading the input.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BEAM/Usage+Guide#UsageGuide-RunaPython-SDKPipeline

when I used `gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt` as the input, the error was `apache_beam.io.filesystem.BeamIOError: Match operation failed with exceptions {'gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt': TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'response_encoding'",)}`

when I used my local file, it seemed it didn't actually read the file, and output nothing. The result didn't include 'has_job', which I am not sure what it actually means https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py#L118.

Answer (score 3):

This error is because your version of google-apitools is too old. You need v0.5.23 or newer to avoid this error.

Beam python has [strict version requirements](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-dependencies/) for dependencies. If you are running Beam 2.11, you need to be using google-apitools v0.5.26.